How to identify faulty updates?
I have been having failures updating Focal -> Jammy on one of my systems.  I just discovered that the subject system has run out of disk space, but freeing up space has not improved the update process.  I suspect that prior updates failed without my paying proper attention.  My bad, but I want to get past this.
So: is it plausible that an update could fail and leave the system in a broken state?  If so, is it possible to identify such updates, or the affected software?  If not, can I somehow do reinstall of all Focal updates?  And if all of those are impossible, must I rebuild the system?

On trying answer 1, I got this message on the last step:
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-software : Depends: libfwupd2 (>= 1.7.9) but 
    1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1.1~1632510283~20.04~5dec90e~dev
    is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

On running apt policy gnome-software I got this response:
gnome-software:
  Installed: 3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0
  Candidate: 3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Version table:
     3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.36.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.0 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.36.0-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages


"is it plausible that an update could fail and leave the system in a broken state?" Very much yes. Like overflowing your auto's petrol tank, it can be a terrible mess to clean up.

You appear to have at least one Pop!_OS repository in your sources

Remove the pop os repository (from Software & Sources -> Other Software). Run sudo apt update, and retry the commands in the answer below

The system does NOT have repositories specific to PopOS.  There are a couple from System76, which provide some drivers and services I use.  I'm not aware of anything specific to Pop OS, and that OS has never been installed here.  How could I investigate to see if something snuck in?

@steeldriver what makes you say that?  There is indeed some System76 software here, but they delivered the system with Ubuntu installed and it has updated just fine since 2016.  Can you point to something specific?

@ForDummies well regardless of the origin 1.5.11-0ubuntu2pop1.1~1632510283~20.04~5dec90e~dev doesn't look like it belongs on an Ubuntu 22.04 system - so it would be helpful if you included your exact OS version and details of the upgrade path

@steeldriver The system was delivered in early July of 2016 with whatever Ubuntu was then current, plus a System76 repository and some installed files.  I did not pay much attention to details, just to the fact that it all worked.  I pretty quickly used advice from the web to change to nearly Xubuntu, without a fresh install.  I may have added some other stuff from System76 to prepare for CUDA coding, which I never got around to.  I have done regular updates and upgrades since, all from Ubuntu using apt-get.  Just guessing from the name of the file, it has to do with firmware upgrades.

@ForDummies can you please [edit] that information into the question, along with the (non-comment) contents of your sources.list file(s) ex. grep -rv '^#' /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d}

I have updated my answer.

Please add the output of apt policy gnome-software to your question.

@OrganicMarble    Appended output of apt policy gnome-software to the question.

I see the installed version of gnome-software does not have a software source. Maybe it's the left over focal version? something is broken in the package system for sure.

Don't use PopOS repositories with Ubuntu repositories.  Mixing and matching like that will lead to issues like these.

Open Software & Sources, and disable all PPAs and 3rd-party repositories (like that of System76). Re-enable them only after the whole upgrade is complete.

One you have enough space (at least 10 GB in the root partition), first, complete all the unfinished package installation with
sudo dpkg --configure -a

Then, run the following commands to fully install all available upgrades.
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop^


Hmm. ubuntu-desktop?  I forgot to mention I'm actually running Xubuntu.  Does this change anything?

Is that circumflex (^) a typo, or do I really put that on the command-line?

Ok. Use xubuntu-desktop instead. And yes, the ^ is necessary

I got an error, and added the error message to the end of the question.
